# I cant'g get virtualenvwrapper to inbstall on Ubuntu where it needs to be

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenvwrapper

I have followed the instructions to the letter on the website.  The problem is inconsistency where things end up.  When I type:

```
which virtualenv
```

I get back

```
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

which looks OK to me (I am not a unix expert).  But after doing

```
pip install virtualenvironmentwrapper
```

I get this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenvwrapper in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied: stevedore in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied: pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
```

What do you do to fix this?

Comment: The output tells you that it is installed already.

Comment: Got that...but, then, how do I get it to be recognized so that if I type 'mkvirtualenv ...' it works?  Right now I get 'command not found'.

Comment: Did you add the line to your `.bashrc` as the documentation explains?

Comment: when I find the hidden file, it is full of stuff that looks nothing like this: it starts with     # ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
    # see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
    # for examples

    # If not running interactively, don't do anything
    case $- in
 *i*) ;;
   *) return;;

Answer (score 0):

It rurns out warpper is not that much more useful.  However, the original problem was never resolved.